# Who owns a value without a let binding?

Tags: rust

Consider the following code:

```
struct MyStruct {
    not_copyable: NotCopyable
}

struct NotCopyable;

fn main() {
    let foo = MyStruct { not_copyable: NotCopyable };
    foo.not_copyable;
    foo.not_copyable;

    // just found out the simpler "foo; foo;" will create the same problem
}
```

This fails to compile with

```
src/main.rs:17:5: 17:21 error: use of moved value: `foo.not_copyable` [E0382]
src/main.rs:17     foo.not_copyable;
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/main.rs:16:5: 16:21 note: `foo.not_copyable` moved here because it has type `NotCopyable`, which is non-copyable
src/main.rs:16     foo.not_copyable;
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
error: aborting due to previous error
```

While I'm still not very versed in the ownership system, I think I get why you couldn't create two `let` bindings to `foo.not_copyable`. But in this case there is no binding. So who owns `not_copyable` here; where did it move?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So who owns `not_copyable here; where did it move?

No one.  The expression `foo.not_copyable` has to pull the value out of the structure, because that value is the result of the expression.  That you don't *do* anything with the value is beside the point; you asked for the value, it gave you the value.

It's possible the compiler *might* be able to optimise this out under certain circumstances, but without that, it's going to move the value like you asked it to.

And yes, `foo;foo;` will do the same thing: just as `NotCopyable` is not copyable, neither is `MyString`.

Comment: So the expression basically "removed" any ownership something might have had on that value?

Comment: It's more like it moved ownership like it *normally* does... except without anyone there to hold it, it moved it right off the side of the desk on to the floor where the office roomba sucked it up.  (Do not take this facetious analogy as an implication that Rust has tracing garbage collection; it doesn't have tiny software roombas going about eating up loose allocations.)

Comment: Ok. Is it correct that `foo.not_copyable` moves two values: `foo` and foo's `not_copyable`?

Comment: No; it only moves `foo.not_copyable`.  If you had two fields in the structure, you could move one, *then* the other.  That said, having moved `non_copyable`, the `foo` struct as a *whole* is effectively moved.

Comment: Phew. My misunderstanding stems from another issue I have but that should be the subject of another question. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I probably meant that `foo` is moved partially. Because that's what the error message says if you try to evaluate `foo` after `foo.not_copyable`.